# Hibernate second level cache commit performance

Tags: hibernate, caching, ehcache

I have recently enabled Hibernate EH cache as a second level cache with query caching, on my java application.

- The application involves bulk insertions ( retrieving data from one
  db, modifying it according to the new schema and saving it in the
  target db)
- After processing a batch of **300** elements, the following hibernate apis are called.
  sesion.**flush**(), session.**clear**(), session.**commit**();
- For the next batch, the **same session** is reused to create a new transaction.
- The 2nd level cache is enabled only for few entities
  which are likely to remain static.
- Queries that are called repeatedly have only been cached.
- The 2nd level cache is distributed, hence cache puts are being replicated across 3-4 nodes

However, benchmark results reveal that after enabling second level cache, the migration process is a lot slower. Commit operations take ~3 times the duration. What exactly happens to the 2nd level cache when calling the hibernate session APIs mentioned above?

Comment: does [this](http://ankursinghal86.blogspot.in/2014/07/how-hibernate-second-level-cache-works.html) help you.

Comment: the blog post does not elucidate the behaviour of second level caches during flushes or commits.